# What is the best way to combine similar dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 3 `df`:

`df_A`:

```
    year  month day  A
0   2014    1   1   15.8
1   2014    1   2   21.0
2   2014    1   3   22.3
3   2014    1   4   20.2
4   2014    1   5   20.0
... ... ... ... ...
```

`df_B`:

```
    year  month day  B
0   2014    1   1   15.8
1   2014    1   2   21.0
2   2014    1   3   22.3
3   2014    1   4   20.2
4   2014    1   5   20.0
... ... ... ... ...
```

`df_C`:

```
    year  month day  C
0   2014    1   1   15.8
1   2014    1   2   21.0
2   2014    1   3   22.3
3   2014    1   4   20.2
4   2014    1   5   20.0
... ... ... ... ...
```

I want to 1) join them side by side; 2) Integrate the 3 date columns into one, which looks like this:

```
     date        A    B    C 
0   2014-1-1    15.8 15.8 15.8
1   2014-1-2    21.0 21.0 21.0
2   2014-1-3    22.3 22.3 22.3
3   2014-1-4    20.2 20.2 20.2
4   2014-1-5    20.0 20.0 20.0
... ... ... ... ...
```

I tried

```
df_A['date']=pd.to_datetime(df_A[['year','month','day']])
```

but it returned

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-88de4e50b4f6> in <module>()
----> 1 df_A['date']=pd.to_datetime(df_A[['year','month','day']])
      2 
      3 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1183             if not (self.name == "loc" and not raise_missing):
   1184                 not_found = list(set(key) - set(ax))
-> 1185                 raise KeyError("{} not in index".format(not_found))
   1186 
   1187           

KeyError: "['year'] not in index"
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your code `df_A['date']=pd.to_datetime(df_A[['year','month','day']])` works as required in pandas version 0.25.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df_result = ((df.set_index(['year','month','day'])
               .join([df1.set_index(['year','month','day']), 
                      df2.set_index(['year','month','day'])]))
               .reset_index())
df_result['date'] = pd.to_datetime((df.year*10000+df.month*100+df.day).apply(str),format='%Y%m%d')
df_result.drop(['year','month','day'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_result

      A     B     C       date
0  15.8  15.8  15.8 2014-01-01
1  21.0  21.0  21.0 2014-01-02
2  22.3  22.3  22.3 2014-01-03
3  20.2  20.2  20.2 2014-01-04
4  20.0  20.0  20.0 2014-01-05
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, we can use a function to clean your dates and then concat along axis =1

```
def create_datetime(dataframe, year="year", month="month", day="day"):
    dataframe["year"] = pd.to_datetime(
        df[year].astype(str) + "-" + df[month].astype(str) + "-" + df[day].astype(str),
        format="%Y-%m-%d",
    )
    dataframe = dataframe.drop([month, day], axis=1)
    dataframe = dataframe.rename(columns={year : 'date'})
    dataframe = dataframe.set_index('date')
    return dataframe
```

---

```
dfA = create_datetime(dfA)

dfB = create_datetime(dfB)

dfC = create_datetime(dfC)

final = pd.concat([dfA,dfB,dfC],axis=1)

               A     C     C
date                        
2014-01-01  15.8  15.8  15.8
2014-01-02  21.0  21.0  21.0
2014-01-03  22.3  22.3  22.3
2014-01-04  20.2  20.2  20.2
2014-01-05  20.0  20.0  20.0
```